Why is there back current from DRV8833 when using PWM in slow decay (braking)?
I setup a circuit to drive a small DC motor and noticed a 0.3V signal on the power rail. The signal has the same 60Hz cycle as the PWM signal. VM is 5V and I am using a slow decay (braking) PWM signal on the DRV8833 input. My CPU is also on the same 5V power so the signal is making the CPU randomly reboot.
My guess is that the breaking somehow causes the signal because the problem does not exist when I use fast decay (no braking).
How can I fix this problem? I could go through the trouble of designing complete power isolation between the DRV8833 and the CPU but I hope there is a simpler solution.


Hi. How are the motors connected? Are you using four motors in one direction or two bidirectional? Where are the flyback diodes? Please add these to the schematic.

I am using 2 bidirectional motors. Motor #1 is connected to MOT1 and MOT2. Motor #2 is connected to MOT3 and MOT4. There are no flyback diodes (problem?).

If you are using the motor in bidirectional mode, then there are two decay modes.
From the datasheet:

As you can see in the diagram, if you turn all the switches off, it goes into fast decay mode. In this mode, via the intrinsic diodes on the Mosfets, the current is injected back into the supply voltage. That's where the ripple comes from.
You can keep the two bottom Mosfets active to go for slow decay. This way, you shouldn't be seeing the ripple in the supply voltage.
On an unrelated topic, although the datasheet didn't say anything about the need for flyback diodes, I still would add external diodes and wouldn't use the intrinsic diode.

Thank you for your comments. In my case, I'm seeing the ripple when using slow decay but not seeing it when using fast decay. It's strange. I will do some experimentation with flyback diodes to see if it can fix the problem.
